# How to Monitor the URL which a user is trying to access?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, proxy, monitoring

Hope my question is clear.

I wish to develop a Internet monitoring system for my office using VB 2008. What i need to get is when a user tries to access internet via any webbrowser, the application we are developing should store that address to a database.

Since this is on a network based project, i would like to know the domain users are online or not

eg..

Fields need to collect

User Name, Machine name, IP address and URL trying to access

Hope this is clear now

Your help much appreciated

Thanks and Regards
Ajith

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of web proxies available which will log client activity - I strongly suggest you use the power of Google to find one and use it instead of trying to write your own :)

At first glance, [this page](http://www.linquist.net/geek/proxy) might be a good starting point for you.